# Road graph tool crashes, but works with sample shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

When I try to calculate the distance between two points using the "Road graph" plugin in QGIS (1.8.0-2, on OSX 10.8.2 ML), QGIS just crashes. It does work with the sample shape file from

http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html

I'm sure it's a problem with my shapefile, but I can't see why it won't work. Even if I extract one single line as a new shapefile, it still crashes (program closes itself).

EDIT:

"QGIS quit unexpectedly
Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.
Ignore / Report... / Reopen"

[image]

EDIT2:

Info from the .prj file:

> PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Filenames:
gsk3c_ruhr_gew_line.sbn
gsk3c_ruhr_gew_line.sbx
gsk3c_ruhr_gew_line.shp
gsk3c_ruhr_gew_line.shx

Plugin settings are the default (do work with sample shape file)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you post the error message? That way it would be easier to troubleshoot it.

Comment: The problem description doesn't contain much information for trouble shooting. Include screenshots, file names, projections used, plugin settings, ...

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I have added additional information

Answer (score 1):

I was now able to solve the problem by taking a shape file that does work (the example sahpefile) and copying the features from my own shape file and pasting them in the example file. Now it is working.

thank you for your time!